# The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found - build is incomplete

Tags: angularjs, plugins, angular-cli, build-error

I am new working in angular project. Trying to build a angular project which is not complete because of the below message.

```
build-prod-linux:
     [exec] The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
     [exec] Result: 1
```

I tried installing yarn, angular-cli (re-installed) yet it shows build successful but because of this message build is incomplete and not able to see the output for my changes. Could you someone help. I looked in other answers but nothing helped so far. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this question is very broad as it is written. Please take a read through [How to create good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your problem.

Comment: I got it working by installing angular-cli again, Issue as there was angular.json file was missing.